# Custom HTML in front of fullcalendar title

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar-2.0.2 in my project. As per the requirement, I need to create a circle in front of the title for process completion. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  theme: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'     
  },

  themeButtonIcons:false,    
  weekNumbers: true,
  fixedWeekCount: false,
  editable: true,
  eventTextColor: 'black',
  eventLimit: true,  
  events: [

    {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: '2014-11-04T12:00:00',
      className: 'complete_task'    
    }
  ]

});
```

```css
.complete_task{
  background-image:url("images/circle_red.png") ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-color:transparent;
  padding-left: 15px;  /* width of the image plus a little extra padding */ 
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

You can define a class with a background image and use it in your array of events. Just add the className property under your start date.